# Using classes across forms in the same project

Tags: c#, winforms, class

Suppose I have a project with several different forms: `Form1`, `Form2`, `Form3` and I also have a class called `CustomTools` which contains often-used **validation procedures and functions**:

```
class CustomTools
{
    bool isNumeric(object input)
    {
        double result;
        if (input == null)
            return false;
        else
        {
            if (double.TryParse(input.ToString(), out result))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, when I try to use `isNumeric` in one of my forms, it doesn't appear in the IntelliSense popup. What's the best way to make this function available in all my forms? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: `but neither has worked for functions or procedures` -- I'm not clear on what you mean by this.

Comment: Assume you want to explore singleton pattern or you want to make that function public static

Comment: In other words, I can't seem to do `CustomTools tools = new CustomTools()` and then run `CustomTools.customFunction()`.

Comment: Why?  Are you getting an error message?  Help us out here.

Comment: Your methods (`functions or procedures`) should be in your class. If its and static class you can use it directly, otherwise you could share a static field with an intance of the class (singleton) or preferibly pass a reference to an object of the class in the constructor. Note: since these are `often-used custom` methods (`procedures and functions`) go for the static class. Please use an static class before attempting singleton.

Comment: Why the close request?  It is a *known* problem with `Form` in that if you try and have a common form base-class (which would be the ideal solution), you run in to all sorts of weird crap.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Several people have indicated through comments, or the fact that they're asking clarifying questions, that the question is unclear.  If it was clear, they wouldn't be making such comments.  I'm honestly surprised there aren't more close votes.  It's not clear at all what the OP is asking about.  As for what you think the question is asking, that is not at all consistent with the OP's earlier comment, indicating that that's *not* the problem that he has.

Comment: There are many ways to design without using code repetition. You have to give more details about what your custom functions do. I would not suggest keeping all functions used in a shared class called `UtilityClass` or something. If you do this, you should explore the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: @Servy, fair point - I'm late to the game.  Happy Christmas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add `public` before your methods.

For example:

```
public bool isNumberic(object input)
{
   ...
}
```

And you might want to make the methods static:

```
public static bool isNumberic(object input)
{
   ...
}
```

So that you can call them simply by:

```
CustomTools.isNumberic(someVariable);
```

Comment: I figured it was something simple that I missed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a service/helper type class with static/shared methods. This conveniently groups your methods in one place and doesn't require an instance. However, this approach only works well with stateless methods. You could also consider a base class that your forms inherit from. This class could house your shared methods. There are many, acceptable, ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 0):

A class is a reference type so all you need is a variable of type `CustomTools` in all three forms. I suggest using properties to set the variables like this

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public CustomTools Tools { get; set; }
}
public class Form2 : Form
{
    public CustomTools Tools { get; set; }
}
public class Form2 : Form
{
    public CustomTools Tools { get; set; }
}
```

and whenever you create a form, assign it the `Tools` property

```
var tools = new CustomTools();
var f1 = new Form1() { Tools = tools };
var f2 = new Form2() { Tools = tools };
var f3 = new Form3() { Tools = tools };
...
f1.Show();
f2.Show();
f3.Show();
```

within each form you use the tools as

```
public void inputTextBox_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var input = (sender as TextBox).Text;
    if( Tools.IsNumeric(input) )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

A better solution is to use Extension Methods though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you implement an Extension method which is available to all classes in the namespace and below:

```
public class Form1
{

    public void inputTextBox_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object input=(sender as Control).Text;
        if (sender.IsNumeric())
        {
        }
    }
}

public static class CustomTools
{
    public static bool IsNumeric(this object item)
    {
        if (item==null) return false;
        double result;
        return double.TryParse(item.ToString(), out result);
    }
}
```